# Nmap scans the host but cannot ping the host

Tags: ping, host, nmap

My laptop is connected to a network where we have routers with filters. I can use nmap to scan alive hosts and I can see open ports (mostly port 80). But then, when I try to ping those hosts, I dont receive any data. Can anyone point out what the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

[edit]

BTW, I can ping my own computer (localhost/my IP address).

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! This is a site for professional sysadmins/network admins. With all due respect, since you don't know the difference between ping/ICMP and TCP, and you're not the person in charge of those routers/filters, this question does not seem to match that specification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because a server or computer has a port open, does not mean it will respond to ICMP packets. Many in fact are specifically configured to not do so.

Comment: Those are not servers, those are just computers just like mine! I can ping my own computer and it's working!

Comment: Computers have firewalls also nowadays.

Comment: Windows 8 for example will not respond to pings by default: http://www.sysprobs.com/how-to-enable-ping-reply-response-in-windows-8-simple-steps

Comment: I can see the webpage hosted by my friend (using Ubuntu) in my network from my computer, but I can't ping him. In that case, firewall allows me to send  request to his port 80, right? (Please, correct me if im wrong)

Comment: That's correct. His firewall drops ICMP packets, but allows TCP packets to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Those hosts can have Windows Firewall service up and running.

You should check firewall rules on those host and verify if they allow **icmp** protocol.

You can read about icmp protocol [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol)